# Filter pyspark DataFrame by max of column having timestamp

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with the below schema and data.

```
schema:[system_name: string, file_name: string, data_tablename: string,  create_date: timestamp]
```

df:

```
+-----------+----------------+------------------+--------------------------+
|system_name|file_name       |data_tablename    |create_date               |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+--------------------------+
|ABC        |abc_11132020    |dbo.refine_abc    |2020-11-13 19:34:01.448957|
|ABC        |abc_11132020    |dbo.refine_abc    |2020-11-13 20:44:26.315801|
|ABC        |abc_11162020_1  |dbo.refine_abc    |2020-11-16 20:07:12.354104|
+-----------+----------------+------------------+--------------------------+
```

I want to filter `df` where `create_date = max(create_date)`

```
max_ts = df.select(max("create_date")).collect()
 
print(max_ts)
[Row(max(create_date)=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 16, 20, 7, 12, 354104))]

print(max_ts[0][0])
2020-11-16 20:07:12.354104
 
file_details=df.filter(df.create_date==max_ts[0][0]).collect()
 
print(file_details) --> returning empty list. I was expecting row having file name:abc_11162020_1.
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the maximum value in a column, you can use `agg()`:

```
max_ts = df.agg({"create_date": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
```

Filter:

```
df.filter(df.create_date==max_ts).show(truncate=False)
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+
|system_name|file_name     |data_tablename|create_date               |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+
|ABC        |abc_11162020_1|dbo.refine_abc|2020-11-16 20:07:12.354104|
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Cena, with agg definitely getting max value which is 2020-11-16 20:07:12.354104.
but when using df.filter(df.create_date==max_ts).show(truncate=False)
, it is returning empty df for me.

Comment: It works for me. Are you able to see the `create_date` column with `2020-11-16 20:07:12.354104` value when you just do `df.show()`?

Comment: yes, able to see 2020-11-16 20:07:12.354104 with df.show().
but filter is not working. It not able to compare max_ts to create_date.
I am able to get it to filter by converting to unix_timestamp though.
do you thik it has to do with version of spark?
I am using databricks with cluster version: 7.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)

Comment: This is just basic filtering and should work irrespective of the version. Conversion to  `unix_timestamp ` isn't needed. Simply doing `max_ts = df.agg({"create_date": "max"}).collect()[0][0]` and `df.filter(df.create_date==max_ts).show()` should work. Try it in a new session/terminal. Can't tell what the problem is without seeing the full code.

Answer (score 0):

By converting timestamp to unix timestamp, able to filter the column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, unix_timestamp 
df=df.withColumn("create_date", unix_timestamp("create_date", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
max_ts = df.select(max("create_date")).collect()
file_details=df.filter(df.create_date==max_ts[0][0]).collect()
```